# AWS amplify v6, using signInWithRedirect instead of auth.federatedSignIn, doesnt open the account.google.com page where I can choose account

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-oauth, google-signin, aws-amplify

Before aws-amplify v6, i was using federatedSignIn to make user login into the website using google. Where clicking the `sign in with google` button was calling the federatedSignIn method which then would redirect the user to a page, where user can choose which google account the user wants to log in with.
After the migration, this is not happening. The google page which shows all the list of accounts which the user can sign in with, is not appearing. (The redirection to account.google.com/o/oauth=?etc..etc.. is not happening) As suggested by the official [doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/auth-migration-guide/#authfederatedsignin)  to use
`await signInWithRedirect({ provider: 'Google' });`

- Ive configured the amplify like this:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        Cognito: {
            userPoolId: 'us-west-xxxxx',
            userPoolClientId: 'xxxxxxx',
            loginWith: {
                oauth: {
                    domain: 'auth.abcdefgh.com',
                    redirectSignIn: ["http://localhost:3000/"],
                    redirectSignOut: ["http://localhost:3000/"],
                    responseType: 'code',
                    scope: ['email', 'openid']
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

- The "sign in with google" button calls this

```
const handleSocialSignIn = async () => {
  await signInWithRedirect({
    provider: 'Google'
  });
}
```

- The signInWithRedirect doesnt return anything. I think this is expected as per the doc.
- I cant use amplifyUI. So the withAuthenticate or  is not possible.
- using react

Ive tried this. But doesnt work. https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/advanced-workflows/#identity-pool-federation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hub.listen like this

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Hub } from "aws-amplify/utils";
import { signInWithRedirect, signOut, getCurrentUser } from "aws-amplify/auth";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [customState, setCustomState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload }) => {
      switch (payload.event) {
        case "signInWithRedirect":
          getUser();
          break;
        case "signInWithRedirect_failure":
          setError("An error has ocurred during the OAuth flow.");
          break;
        case "customOAuthState":
          setCustomState(payload.data); // this is the customState provided on signInWithRedirect function
          break;
      }
    });

    getUser();

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
      setUser(currentUser);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      console.log("Not signed in");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ customState: "shopping-cart"})}>Open Hosted UI</button>
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Facebook", customState: "shopping-cart" })}>
        Open Facebook
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Google", customState: "shopping-cart" })}>
        Open Google
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Amazon", customState: "shopping-cart" })}>
        Open Amazon
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect({ provider: "Apple", customState: "shopping-cart" })}>
        Open Apple
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
      <div>{user?.username}</div>
      <div>{customState}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should add the proper explanation to the code properly for future reference and better understanding for others.